# Powershell script to output list of devices and when joined to domain

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory

im new to learning scripting and have a question about my script below so would be grateful for some help.

im trying to get some data from AD, that gives me a list of the laptops in a particular OU. for each of the laptops id like to know its computer Name, description,and when it was created and a datetime stamp. i wrote something simple below and i can get it to work if i give it a single value of a laptop name but gives an error if i want it to look at all the objects in the OU. it gives me the error directory object not found

```
$ouPath = "OU=company1,OU=folder1,OU=subfolder2,DC=company1,DC=com" 
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $ouPath -Filter * -Properties * | Select Name, whenCreated, Created, CreateTimeStamp
```

if i use -Identity and a specific laptop name then it brings back the data fine, but I want it to look in that particular OU (which has all the laptops listed) and for each laptop bring back the above field data? or do i need to loop through and provide a list of laptop names to it?

thanks for your help

brings up error directory object not found

Comment: If you do `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "name -eq 'company1'"` do you find any result? If so, does the `DistinguishedName` attribute on that result matches exactly with what you have in `$ouPath` ?

Comment: If you want the description included in the output then you need to include it in the list of property names passed to `Select`: `... |Select Name, Description, whenCreated`